# Random position of buttons in Android App

Tags: android

i have this method for random position of a button:

```
public void randomButton(Button btn) {
    LayoutParams absParams = (LayoutParams) btn.getLayoutParams();
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    absParams.leftMargin = btn.getWidth() + new Random().nextInt(displaymetrics.widthPixels - 2 * btn.getWidth());
    absParams.topMargin = btn.getHeight() + new Random().nextInt(displaymetrics.heightPixels - 3 * btn.getHeight());
    btn.setLayoutParams(absParams);
}
```

It is possible to show multiple buttons like this, but not to interleave between them?